# How do I center a div with a max-width, and if the window is smaller than the div, the div will still have some margin space on each side?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a max-width, and is centered:

```
.div1 {
    background-color: #eee;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The div gets automatically centered, but I want it to also have a margin of 20px on the left and right side, if the window gets smaller than 600px.

Here is the JSFiddle of what I am trying to accomplish: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gg8tkyb1/) . I would like to add the properties of div2 to div1, without losing the ability to center div1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a media query to specify when to override the margins and give them 20px on each side.

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    background-color: #eee;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .div1 {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I give div1 a margin of 20px on the left and right side, if the window is smaller than 600px?

Comment: use media query then.

Answer (score 0):

use margin-left:auto
    margin-right:auto

when the screen is bigger than 600px it 'll automatically come to the middle of the page